# htaccess - passing request uri as a parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

What I'm trying to do is as follows:

1. Redirect user to another address using htaccess.
2. Pass the given URL as a parameter to the new url

So when the user visits any page on **http://domainA.com/**
he should be redirected to: http://domainB.com/?referer=http://domainA.com/

What I keep failing on, is retrieving the full URL the user came from BEFORE the redirection.

One of the things I tried and failed miserably:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domainB.com/?referer=%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I tried to keep my question simple, as more complex questions tend to remain unanswered,
So I will sharpen my question, although **there's a good answer to the original one**.

So to be more specific about what I'm trying to achieve:
Both domains are hosted on the same host, and points to exact same files.
So **domainA.com/file1.html** and **domainB.com/file1.html** will display the same file.

What I want domainA to do, is to deliver all requests to a file called listener.php.
So that all requests to domainA should be like so:

1. User enters http://domainA.com/file1.html
2. Server request behind the scenes is actually: /listener.php?actualRequest=http://domainA.com/file1.html

I want this functionality to be on the server side so that the url will remain normal.

I went for 2 domains as I wanted to avoid redirect loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domainA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domainB.com/?referer=http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```

This handles both `http://` and `https://` URLs.

---

**EDIT:** As per edited question you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domainA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^listener\.php$ /listener.php?actualRequest=http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I tried to use this code, for some reason it doesn't work. have you tested it yourself?

Comment: I don't post untested code in my answers of course it is tested and working code. For which URL it din't work and where is this .htaccess located? Are there more rules?

Comment: I see. Well I tried to use it when domainA was an IP address of the server (without a domain at the moment) and domainB was a .com domain of mine. The file is located at the root folder, exactly where the index of the site is. and nope, no other rules. it's purely your code in it.

Comment: My bad. I badly edited it to fit my domains, it does work. another question though, is it possible to have this kind of a redirection without changing the url seen by the user?

Comment: I see, well you did answer my question, but I realized I should've asked this question differently, I will edit it with a bit more info and I'd really appreciate it if you'll have any solution for my case.